# Can copy value from java script variable to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

can I assign value to php variable with java script. I want to copy a java script variable's value to  php variable . Is it possible ?

Comment: @Quentin the other way around!

Comment: @zoranc — No, it's about passing data from JS to PHP which is what that question is about.

Comment: that title is very deceiving then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is on the client side, whereas PHP executes on the server side. PHP variables can be assigned to javascript variables, but otherwise no.